# Generate title automatically based on the most repeated word in text using php

Tags: php

I would like to generate a title automatically based on the most repeated word in a text using PHP.
Example: if the the word "PHP" is repeated the most in a text The title would be : "The text is about PHP".... and so on.
I have no clue what to do or from where to start.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Where did you got struck? As a pretty dumb approach, you could split  your input to words into an array and use [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) for start.

Comment: As I said. I have no clue what to do in this case :\

Comment: what research have you done so far to solve this problem yourself? or are you simply asking stackoverflow to do your homework for you?

Comment: I've researched  on google but I found nothing. and about the homework, I really did my best to think about an idea that will solve me this problem but I stuck. I thought about counting words but I stuck on how to know which word is most repeated within the text. By the way, I'm still a newbie in programming using PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if i must complete your homework assignment for you, i require full attribution within the paper and the link to this question also in said paper.

i also require that you actually read, understand and attempt to run this code to enable you to understand it.

```
//get all the test from the file
$text_from_file = file_get_contents("filename.txt");

//get all the words within that text
$words = str_word_count($text_from_file , 1);

//count up all the unique words within the array
$unique = array_count_values($words);

//sort by most to least frequent
arsort($unique); //arsort required to keep keys and values together

//since we dont know the key values here, we need to use foreach
foreach($unique as $key => $val) {
  echo("The most common word is " . $key . " which occurs " . $val . " times");

  break; //always break after the first echo
}
```

Comment: lol, Thank you so much for your help. Your code is what I was searcheing for :) Thank you once again. And about the homework. I'm gonna do what your requirment :P

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function mostRepeated($string = false, $words_num = 5) {
    $string = strtolower($string);
    // extend this array
    $omit_words = array('the', 'a', 'an', 'in', 'at', 'by', 'of', 'was', 'is', 'he', 'she');

    $words = explode(' ', $string);
    foreach($words as $k => $v) {
        if(in_array($word, $omit_words)) unset($words[$k]);
    }

    $count = array_count_values($words);
    arsort($count);
    $result = array();
    foreach($count as $k => $v) {
       $result[] = $k;
    }

    return $result;
}

$text = 'PHP foo Bar php foO pHp';
$most_repeated_words_array = mostRepeated($text, 3);
print_r($most_repeated_words_array);
?>
```

output:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => php
    [1] => foo
    [2] => bar
)
```

Answer (score 0):

using

```
print_r( array_count_values(str_word_count($text, 1)) );
```

will give you a count of all words. You can then choose the top one when sorted ?

```
rsort
```

will give you a sorted array from high to low

Comment: But how to count the words and know the most repeated word in a text?

Comment: But how to exclude prepositions and other stuffs like:I, you, him, the ....etc to be counted ?

Comment: Dont choose the top value. That will give you the count you can easily loop though and apply a filter

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try and give my feedback. Thank you